# How to set Lion built-in FTP Server auto run off

Tags: macos, ftp, built-in

I set FTP Server by using Rumpus Server application.

But Lion's built-in FTP Server is running on the front.

So if I try to connect my FTP Server out of my LAN, I can only connect to the built-in FTP Server despite I wanted to connect Rumpus FTP Server.

It can be solved by unload the built-in FTP Server(using sudo -s launchctl unload...) but every after rebooting I should set it because it is set to run automatically in every booting.

How can I set the auto run off?

Mac mini, Mac OS X (10.7.1)

Comment: Probably better to ask at http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist and make sure that the Disabled key is set to true not false and then reboot:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <true/>
```

Comment: I edited the file by using sudo nano in terminal, and I saved by control + O but after reboot it changed <key>false</key> again. How can I save the file?

Comment: Please post the results of the following:  netstat -an|grep *.21

Comment: It looks like this was closed.  If you rename the ftp.plist file, maybe that'll help (at your own risk, though).

Comment: the following is the result of netstat after reboot : http://imgur.com/Ra34O

Comment: I solved this problem by changing built-in ftp server's port to 9221 in etc/services file.